# AppleScript to select a sentence in mac Pages

Tags: applescript

I would like to use a hotkey to select the current sentence my cursor is on. I am aware that in Word you can just triple click f8. But Pages has no such functionality. You can select words or paragraphs but not sentences. I am hoping there is a way to make an AppleScript do it, but so far I'm stumped. Ideas?

I would post code, but I don't have any as I'm unsure where to begin.

I would also be happy to use any other coding language, but AppleScript seems the most organic or native to Pages. However, I could be wrong?